# Non-isolating group labeling of a hypergraph

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics

Let $(G,+,0)$ be an abelian group, $H=(V,\mathcal{E})$ is a $r$-uniform hypergraph. Let $\ell:V\to G$ be a labelling of the vertices. The label of an edge is the sum of the label of the vertices, so $\ell(X) = \sum_{x\in X} \ell(x)$.

A labeling isolates an edge $e$, if $\ell(e)\neq \ell(e')$ for every $e'\in \mathcal{E}$ distinct from $e$. A labeling is non-isolating, if no edge is isolated.

We are interested in study for which hypergraphs, all the $G$-labelings are non-isolating.

For example, say $H$ is the complete $r$-uniform hypergraph on at least $2r$ vertices, where $r\geq |G|+1$, then every $G$-labeling is non-isolating. Indeed, consider any edge $X$, we take any injection $f:X\to \bar{X}$. Note $\ell(X-Y+f(Y)) = \ell(X)+\sum_{y\in Y} \ell(f(y))-\ell(y)$. Let $\ell'(y) = \ell(f(y))-\ell(y)$, then we claim there exists a $|Y|\leq |G|$ such that $\sum_{y\in Y} \ell'(y) = 0$, this is because the Davenport constant of $G$ is at most $|G|$. Hence take such $Y$, we have $\ell(X-Y+f(Y))=\ell(X)$.

But much sparser $r$-uniform hyerpgraph on at least $2r$ vertcies can also force all $G$-labeling to be non-isolating. For example, let the hypergraph edges be the bases of a strongly base-orderable matroid of rank $r$, such that every base's complement also contains a base.

I'm mostly interested in if there are studies on which hypergraph density conditions that forces all $G$-labeling to be non-isolating.

**Motivation:** I'm trying to show that there is some function $g$, such that if $H$ is the bases of a rank $r\geq g(G)$ block matroid(the groundset partitions to two bases), then all $G$-labeling are non-isolating.